# Adding a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code that adds a new line to my spreadsheet with the information that users enter into a user-form. The problem I'm having is that I have formulas in two of the columns that I need to be carried into the new rows. I have tried several different ways to do this but keep receiving an error message. The formula I need carries is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$E$3:$E$1000,MATCH($B5&"-"&$A5,INDEX(Equipment!$B$3:$B$1000&"-"&Equipment!$A$3:$A$1000,0),0)),"")
```

The values that change line to line are the B and A cells after the MATCH command (in this case $B5 and $A5). Can anyone help me figure out how to convert this to VBA syntax so that I can add it to my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll want set your Range to `.FormulaArray = "=yourformulahere...`  and make sure your quotes are double quotes.  Like `%B5&""-""&$A5`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But I have tried this and it is still returning an error.

Comment: @madeline123456789 try my answer and code below

Answer (score 0):

I Converted this formula, and tested it in a loop.
The formula is copied to **Column D** from **rows 11 to 20**, where **$B5** and **$A5** change according to whatever row they are (I hope I understand what you meant).

```
Sub ConvertFormula()

' modify to where (worksheet) you want to copy this formula    
Set eqp_sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Equipment")

' modify this according to whatever rows and column you want this formula copied
For i = 11 To 20
    eqp_sht.Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$E$3:$E$1000,MATCH($B" & i & "&-$A" & i & ",INDEX(Equipment!$B$3:$B$1000&-Equipment!$A$3:$A$1000,0),0))," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
Next

End Sub
```